# Determining whether or not a resistor is in tolerance

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out how to write a function which will determine whether or not a resistor is within tolerance. The question states "The function determines if the measured resistance value is in or out of tolerance."  I have already created arrays with the following values, where column 1 is 'tolerance percentage values', column 2 is 'lower tolerance values' and column 3 is 'upper tolerance values. I am a bit confused as to how to incorporate the 'in' or 'out' into the output of the function.

[image: Array Values]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to test if `A` is in between `B-tol` and `B+tol`? What is the difficulty? Where did you get stuck? Please show that you tried and tell us why it is not the right solution! That will help give you a good answer.

Comment: To be honest, I am having a really difficult time getting started on how to proceed with parts 6-8. It seems that I would write an "if" "then" statement do determine if the resistance value is "in" or "out. I think I may just be reading to much into the problem because the way it is explained has me very confused. I am not asking anyone to give me the answers, I have just really been struggling with this course and all class sections only have one hour per week for questions about the recorded lectures.

Comment: I added the questions and my programming thus far to the original post.

Comment: function [InOut , testedResistor] = checkResistor(nominalValue, testedResistor, toleranceValue)

allowedVariance = nominalValue * toleranceValue; % calculating allowed variance for resistor
highResistorValue = nominalValue + allowedVariance; % calculating high resistor value
lowResistorValue = nominalValue - allowedVariance; % calculating low resistor value
if (testedResistor > highResistorValue) & (testedResistor < lowResistorValue) % testing for resistor in acceptable range
    InOut = "out";
else 
    InOut = "in";

Answer (score 0):

You were doing a great job proceeding with the steps. To find the lowest and highest acceptable resistors that are within tolerance simply multiply the nominal resistor value (ideal value) by the multipliers you created in the previous steps. The `Tolerance_Specification` in this question is passed as a row vector and can be spit into three parts by indexing. The the `Lower_Tolerance_Multiplier` can be accessed using index 2 and the `Upper_Tolerance_Multiplier` using index 3.

[image: Tolerance Specification Input]

---

```
%*************************************************************************%
%PRECEEDING SETUP STEPS 1 TO 5%
%*************************************************************************%
Tolerances_Percentages = [1 2 0.5 0.25 0.1 5 10];
Tolerances_Percentages = sort(Tolerances_Percentages);

Lower_Tolerance_Multipliers = ((100-Tolerances_Percentages)./100);
Upper_Tolerance_Multipliers = ((100+Tolerances_Percentages)./100);

Tolerance = [Tolerances_Percentages.' Lower_Tolerance_Multipliers.' Upper_Tolerance_Multipliers.'];

%*************************************************************************%
%LOCAL FUNCTION CALL%
%*************************************************************************%
clc;

%Function inputs%
Nominal_Value = 1; %The ideal resistance value%
Measured_Resistance = 1.1; %The actual resistance value when measured%
Tolerance_Specification = Tolerance(4,:);

[Is_It_In_Tolerance,Measured_Resistance] = Check_Resistor(Nominal_Value,Measured_Resistance,Tolerance_Specification);
fprintf("The resistor with measured/tested resistance %f is %s tolerance\n",Measured_Resistance,Is_It_In_Tolerance);

%*************************************************************************%
%LOCAL FUNCTION: CHECK RESISTOR%
%*************************************************************************%

function [Is_It_In_Tolerance,Measured_Resistance] = Check_Resistor(Nominal_Value,Measured_Resistance,Tolerance_Specification)

fprintf("The tolerance selected is %.2f percent\n",Tolerance_Specification(1));

Lower_Tolerance_Multiplier = Tolerance_Specification(2);
Upper_Tolerance_Multiplier = Tolerance_Specification(3);

Lowest_Acceptable_Resistance = Lower_Tolerance_Multiplier*Nominal_Value;
Highest_Acceptable_Resistance = Upper_Tolerance_Multiplier*Nominal_Value;

fprintf("The lowest acceptable resistance is %f\n",Lowest_Acceptable_Resistance);
fprintf("The highest acceptable resistance is %f\n\n",Highest_Acceptable_Resistance);

if (Lowest_Acceptable_Resistance <= Measured_Resistance) && (Measured_Resistance <= Highest_Acceptable_Resistance)
Is_It_In_Tolerance = "in";
else    
Is_It_In_Tolerance = "out";
end


end
```